# how to use/configure routing in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

When it's called /api/Games/aaa, I want method `Get(string deviceId = "")` to be run. But when it's called api/Games/GameById/TaskId I want method `GameById(int id)` to be run. But it not working, especially second method.

Controller:

```
public class GamesController : ApiController
    {
        private List<Game> _gamesRepository;


        public GamesController()
        {
            _gamesRepository = CreateGamesRepository();
        }



        // GET api/Games/DeviceId
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Game> Get(string deviceId = "")
        {
            IEnumerable<Game> result;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceId))
            {
                result = _gamesRepository.AsEnumerable();
            }
            else
            {
                result = _gamesRepository.Where(x => x.DeviceId == deviceId).AsEnumerable();
            }
            return result;

        }


        // GET api/Games/GameById/Id
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Game> GameById(int id)
        {
            IEnumerable<Game> result;

            result = _gamesRepository.Where(x => x.TaskId == id).AsEnumerable();

            return result;

        }
```

Routing:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GamesRoute",
            url: "api/{controller}/{deviceId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "controller", action = "get", deviceId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

            routes.MapRoute(
           name: "GamesRoute2",
           url: "api/games/GameById/{id}",
                // defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                defaults: new { controller = "games", action = "GameById" },
                constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
       );
```

Model:

```
   public class Game
    {
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public string SalesForceId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was your question answered by any answers below?

Comment: I have to admit :) ... that no:). I had just mistaken 2 files: RouteConfig  and WebApiConfig:). when I used webapiconfig, all works as expected:)

Comment: Can you please either post your solution as an answer or close your question (or select an answer below)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting up the RouteParameters to optional?

```
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Answer (score 0):

The order your map routes is important as first route matched wins and the framework stops looking for more routes.

General routes should be added after more specific routes.

```
public static class WebApiConfig {

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {

         config.Routes.MapRoute(
           name: "GamesRoute2",
           routeTemplate: "api/games/GameById/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "games", action = "GameById" },
           constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GamesRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{deviceId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "controller", action = "get", deviceId = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but  when call `http://localhost:49296/api/Games/GameById/11` is run, the result is 'The resource cannot be found'

Comment: When call `http://localhost:49296/api/Games/aaa` is run. Error is '<Error>
<Message>The request is invalid.</Message>
<MessageDetail>
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Int29MockedBackend.Models.Game] GameById(Int32)' in 'Int29MockedBackend.Controllers.GamesController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>' . THe same as before change.

Comment: Wait. you are configuring the wrong routes. is your controller suppose to be `ApiController` or normal Mvc `Controller`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't personally think you should need to map every single route in your Web API Config. Use an architecture that is sustainable and supports the type of design that you want to work with.

In your case, I would use an a more descriptive URI for my APIs by using this configuration in WebApiConfig :

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

What this does is allow you to specify an `/action` in your URI that lets you be very explicit in your calls. Your endpoints would then become :

```
/api/games/getById?id=1
/api/games/get?"Test"
```

### EDIT

If you want a route to match exactly `api/games/{parameter}` then I would add a Route Attribute on that method, like this:

```
[Route("api/games/{id}")]
public IEnumerable<Game> Get(string deviceId = "")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Suppose I need to use format: api/games/aaa, api/Games/GameById/TaskId . I have existign API, I just want to switch server name to use it.